# CART - ERROR while creating predict values

Tags: r, cart-analysis

I split the original dataset with 0.7, checked prop.table. achieved best proportion of train & test data.

after creating classification tree, applied bestcp value and pruned tree.

while i attempt to run -

```
bank3train$predict= predict(prunedtree,data= bank3train, type = 'class')
```

I get an error as -

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, predict, value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
>   : replacement has 5000 rows, data has 3202

checked in google - was told because of NA values - but NA values were treated by omiting the rows.

please advise corrective action.

Comment: If those `NA` values were in a factor, try `?droplevels` after omiting the rows.

Comment: Not `data` should be `newdata`  Try `bank3train$predict= predict(prunedtree, newdata= bank3train, type = 'class')`

Comment: G5W - i tried your advise, got a error as below -Error: variables ‘Age (in years)’, ‘Experience (in years)’, ‘Family members’, ‘Education’ were specified with different types from the fit